# How can I parse JSON data from URL in a background thread in Android (Preferably using Work Manager)?

Tags: java, android, json, rest, background

I've tried many different solutions such as using asyncTask and Work Manager but I can't seem to be able to transfer the parsed data from the background thread to my activity/class. I even tried working around it by attempting to write the parsed string into SharedPreferences, but I wasn't able to do it in the background thread method. Whenever I attempt to get the parsed string from my activity, it always returns a null string. I've fallen way behind schedule and am at a loss on what to do, I'll just post the request and the code for my current Work Manager request, I would greatly appreciate it if someone could help me out with this:

```
        String taskJSON;
        WorkRequest ReadWorkRequest =
                new OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(ReadWorker.class)
                        .build();
        WorkManager
                .getInstance(this)
                .enqueue(ReadWorkRequest);
        WorkManager.getInstance(this).getWorkInfoByIdLiveData(ReadWorkRequest.getId())
                .observe(this, info -> {
                    if (info != null && info.getState().isFinished()) {
                        String myResult = info.getOutputData().getString("tasks:");
                        taskJSON=myResult;
                    }
                });
```

Above is the work manager request and here's the class:

```
public class ReadWorker extends Worker {
    public ReadWorker(
            @NonNull Context context,
            @NonNull WorkerParameters params) {
        super(context, params);
    }


    @Override
    public Result doWork() {
        ArrayList<Task> taskList = new ArrayList<>();
        Data output = null;
        String json = "";
        String readTasksURL = "http://10.0.2.2/BD2/tasks/read";
        try {
            json = readUrl(readTasksURL);
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            Task object = gson.fromJson(json, Task.class);
            taskList.add(object);
            output = new Data.Builder().putString("tasks:",json).build();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Indicate whether the work finished successfully with the Result
        return Result.success(output);
    }

    private static String readUrl(String urlString) throws Exception {
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        String test = "";
        try {
            URL url = new URL(urlString);
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
            int read;
            char[] chars = new char[1024];
            while ((read = reader.read(chars)) != -1)
                buffer.append(chars, 0, read);
            test = buffer.toString();
            reader.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return test;

    }
}
```

Comment: That's not how you make a network call in Android. I strongly recommend you take a look at the official training guides from Google here. That will teach you what you need to know in no time at all
https://developer.android.com/courses/android-basics-kotlin/course

Comment: @IvanWooll Thank you, but honestly I don't have time to sift through the entire course as my project is due in a very short time, plus I'm coding in java and I have no familiarity with kotlin

Comment: Check out Retrofit. It's the industry standard.
https://square.github.io/retrofit/